Как прописать программу в автозагрузку если windows на китайском?
Если windows на китайском, или ещё каком-то не русском и не английском языке, то системные папки (и автозагрузка) тоже на китайском. Но как в этом случае произвести поиск папки автозагрузки? Переводить программу на все языки?

Через реестр добавляйте в автозапуск

звучит как какой-то анекдот :)

" как в этом случае произвести поиск папки автозагрузки" - стоит уточнить какую именно папку вы имеете ввиду, например, на английском Windows.

Получить путь к папке автозапуска можно через реестр:
reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Startup

или отрыть папку через
start shell:startup

Но раз уж всё равно лезть в реестр — добавляйте автозапуск через реестр.

Либо просто помещать файл по пути:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup


Да, но если винда будет не на английском языке, а например,  на китайском, то этот путь будет уже другой т.к. он будет на ийроглифах

@МихаилЮров, какая часть из пути будет из иероглифов?

Grundy, весь путь всегда на том же языке что и сама Windows. То есть весь путь будет на китайском.

@МихаилЮров, можешь показать пример, как это выглядит у тебя? и какая версия windows?

Grundy, Пример кода или пути до автозагрузки? Виндовс 10

@МихаилЮров пример пути. Как правило английские пути работают, потому что на них символические ссылки сделаны с локализованных, например: Мои документы   -> [C:\Users\Grundy\Documents]

@Grundy то есть прописав путь на английском этот путь сработает вне зависимости от языка системы? А ШО, ТАК МОЖНО БЫЛО??? БЛАГОДАРЮ!

@МихаилЮров, да, должен работать, по крайней мере в проводнике. Если из кода - нужно проверить
